# Date marked from Info-path forms into Calendar

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, calendar, sharepoint-calendar, notifications

I have 4 info-path forms published in SharePoint online. Each form has date field in it.   I want that the SharePoint/outlook calendar, of the user (who filed the form), will be marked(as an event) against the date field from any of the form he/she filled up.

Comment: Can you expand the question a bit more with some detail, it's a little hard to understand what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: suppose user filled a form which has a date field (say: Next Payment Due On)        So, I want that date from Next Payment Due On  field to be marked as an event in that particular User's Outlook Calendar or SharePoint Calendar, when user submit the form .

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box no.

Your non-programming way of a possible solution:

1. Create a task list to capture tasks
2. Create a workflow on the form library.  Promote the infopath date item to a SharePoint field and when the form is saved, have the workflow create a task in the task list.
3. Have users connect the task list to Outlook.

The other options available requires custom scripting or programming to reach the Exchange Web Services.